# Exporting charts to PDF doesn't work without alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspdf

I'm trying to export all the charts to a single pdf, one after another. Everything works fine with one alert message, but the code doesn't work without `alert()` method.

Here is my code:

```
function exportChartsToPDF(){
    for( i=0; i<count;i++){
        alert();//<-----this one
        //converting svg to canvas here, one by one
        image.onload = function() {
            //printing image on canvas1,2,3...so on
        };
    }
    //getting imagedata from canvas 1,2,3,... and adding to pdf 
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        var canvas_t = document.getElementById("canvas"+(i+1));
        canvasdata = canvas_t.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
        pdf.addImage(canvasdata, "JPEG", 0,i*graph_h,graph_w,graph_h);
    }
    pdf.save("download.pdf");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean it `works with one alert message but the code doesn't work with alert() method`? What are you trying to `alert()`?

Comment: i think first you create object of image likr this and use var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
   alert("image is loaded");
}

Answer (score 0):

You are adding images to your canvas as they load, but you're not waiting until all have loaded before you render your PDFs.

The alert is probably just giving them time to load in prior to the render.